# How to reduce the flavour of orange zest in chicken?

Tags: chicken, oranges

I recently tried to make orange chicken and the recipe required  the zest of one orange. Well I added too much zest and the orange peel flavor is overpowering. How can I reduce that flavor?

Comment: Can we assume the question is about fixing the leftovers? You could try building a new sauce around the protein (keeping what is on it as marinade), or turning the whole affair into a soup (often a way to salvage stir fried dishes), or maybe adding a lot of neutral vegetable filler (shredded napa cabbage, beansprouts,potatoes...from experience with similar over-oranged dishes: no shiitake or other sharp tasting ingredients!)... no guarantees there, depends on how overpowering the current condition is...

Answer (score 2):

rackandboneman has excellent suggestions. If I may add one more, I would suggest adding some fairly strong tastes to reduce the prominence of the orange. Some soy, garlic and honey would go a long way toward turning the orange into a passable teriyaki.

Answer (score 0):

jist found this.. as I am working on sams issues. I am using leftover orange marmalade in place of orange juice (nobody liked the marmalade so I needed to use it somehow). It has a very strong tangy zest taste. I have included ginger root and garlic, salt, coconut aminos or soy sauce, rice vinegar, brown sugar and diluted with water. While it still has tang.. I think it is definitely much more palatable and hoping it will be even more so once used with the chicken or veggies added to it.